# How to determine what configuration options were used for MySQL server from Ubuntu Packages?

Tags: mysql

How can I get compilation options that was used for mysql-server from Ubuntu packages?
I fetched sources using:

```
apt-get source mysql-server
```

But I have to run configure:

```
./configure
```

Only then I have compilation options, but they are not the same with that used for compilation.

I need exactly the same compilation options for [Pinba](http://pinba.org/wiki/Manual%3aInstallation) plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

command line: `mysqlbug`

Look for `Configure command:` at the bottom for all the options.